# Have permission to read video files but not image files in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, phasset, avasset

I wrote an image picker (**NOT** `UIImagePickerController`) in Swift, upon pressing "Done", I return the URLs of selected PHAssets (images or videos or both), and then upload them to firebase storage.

URL of an image looks like this: `file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/101APPLE/IMG_1239.PNG`

URL of a video looks like this: `file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/101APPLE/IMG_1227.MOV`

Then I display the PHAsset. There was no problem playing a video asset:

```
let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
playerLayer.frame = view.frame
playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
player.play()
```

But when I try to display the image using its URL, I get a "do not have permission to read file" error:

```
do {
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
    imageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

I do have permission to access user's photo library, that's why the image picker is working fine. I just can't read image files using their URLs.

I'm thinking, maybe I should copy image assets to a temp file and read it from there, but it doesn't make any sense why a video asset is readable but not an image asset.

**--------------UPDATE--------------**

This is how I get urls of a PHAsset

```
extension PHAsset {
    func getURL(completionHandler : @escaping ((_ responseURL : URL?) -> Void)) {
        if self.mediaType == .image {
            let options = PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions()
            options.canHandleAdjustmentData = { (adjustmeta: PHAdjustmentData) -> Bool in
                return true
            }
            self.requestContentEditingInput(with: options, completionHandler: { (contentEditingInput: PHContentEditingInput?, info: [AnyHashable : Any]) in
                completionHandler(contentEditingInput!.fullSizeImageURL as URL?)
            })
        } else if self.mediaType == .video {
            let options = PHVideoRequestOptions()
            options.version = .original
            PHImageManager.default().requestAVAsset(forVideo: self, options: options, resultHandler: {(asset: AVAsset?, audioMix: AVAudioMix?, info: [AnyHashable : Any]?) in
                if let urlAsset = asset as? AVURLAsset {
                    let localVideoUrl: URL = urlAsset.url as URL
                    completionHandler(localVideoUrl)
                } else {
                    completionHandler(nil)
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with images versus video. You would not be able to directly access the data of a video using its URL any more than you can access the data of an image from its URL.

Comment: @rmaddy, Makes sense. Do you think my image picker should copy the selected assets to a temp file and then read from there? I have other options such as returning data of selected assets, but it causes memory leak when I try to do so

Comment: You don't have permission to copy the asset using its URL. You need to use the APIs of AVFoundation to access the data of an asset.

Comment: @K.Wu At the time of displaying the image, do you have the `asset` reference or just the `url`?

Comment: @staticVoidMan, the url only. I'm open to changing the data returned by the image picker actually. At first my image picker returns asset's data by calling `imageManager.requestImageData...`, but for large images such as GIF images, the memory usage is significant, it consumes 20+MB more memory each time a GIF is selected. After uploaded, the memory usage stays there, therefore, if a user uploads 1 GIF at a time and do it repeatedly, the app will crash due to memory leak. That's why my image picker returns URLs instead. Do you think I should do it this way?

Comment: @K.Wu Due to sandboxing, you cannot access a `url` outside the app scope and so `Data(contentsOf:)` won't work. However, as an alternative, have you looked at `PHAssets.fetchAssets(withLocalIdentifiers:options:)`? For this, you should be saving the `asset`'s `localIdentifier`s instead of `url`s and then you will be able to reload the `asset` solely on it's `localIdentifier`.

Comment: @K.Wu Btw, could you show us the code snippet that fetches these `url`s. Just want to have a look at what you're doing. Basically enough code to replicate your problem.

Comment: @staticVoidMan, thank you, i've updated the question

Comment: @K.Wu Ok, so the first time you get a `PHAsset`, instead of getting it's `url`, just save it's `localIdentifier` i.e. `asset.localIdentifier`. Then whenever you need to access the `PHAsset`, do `PHAssets.fetchAssets(withLocalIdentifiers:options:)` to get the appropriate asset and then your `myPHAsset.getURL(completionHandler:)` to get `url` in order to load it.

Comment: @staticVoidMan, Awesome! That works! If you post the answer below, I will accept it. Unless you don't care about reputations, then I will come back here later to post the answer

Comment: @K.Wu Will add answer :) Alongwith some simple code snippets for others. Also we'll do something that will remove the need for your `getURL(completionHandler:)` ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apps in iOS run in a sandbox mode which prevents it from accessing files outside it's own scope.
A url such as:

> file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/101APPLE/...

is not in your app's scope and hence is not directly accessible via `Data(contentsOf:)`.

`AVPlayer`, however, is able to access outside `url`s because it's got special entitlement and that's why you were able to load video assets using the `url`.

To load an image from the `url`, we would have used this `url` within `PHAssets.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs:options:)` to get back the `PHAsset` in order to load it, but that method has been deprecated in iOS 11.

As an alternative, `PHAssets.fetchAssets(withLocalIdentifiers:options:)` is available but in order to use it, you will need to provide it a `localIdentifier`.
For that, instead of saving the `url`, you should be saving the `PHAsset`s `localIdentifier`s.

---

#### Summary:

1. Get your `PHAsset`s
2. Save the `asset.localIdentifier`s instead of their `url`s
3. When required, get back a `PHAsset` using [<sup>[1]</sup>](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos/phasset/1624732-fetchassets):

   ```
   PHAssets.fetchAssets(withLocalIdentifiers:options:)
   ```
4. Process the `PHAsset` according to it's `mediaType`

   - For Image [<sup>[2]</sup>](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos/phimagemanager/1616957-requestimagedata):

     ```
     PHImageManager().requestImageData(for:options:resultHandler:)
     ```
   - For Video [<sup>[3]</sup>](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos/phimagemanager/1616935-requestavasset):

     ```
     PHImageManager().requestAVAsset(forVideo:options:resultHandler:)
     ```

---

### General Example:

***Warning:*** `fatalError()` has been used to deliberately terminate the app if something is wrong in your set up.
If it crashes then check your `Info.plist` for `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` and/or permission status to the Photo library via `PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization(_:)`

1. Demo function to get latest asset (image/video; you decide)

   ```
   func getLatestAsset(for type: PHAssetMediaType) {
       let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
       fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key:"creationDate",
                                                        ascending: false)]
       fetchOptions.fetchLimit = 2

       let fetchResult: PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: type,
                                                            options: fetchOptions)

       guard let asset = fetchResult.firstObject else { fatalError("Unable to fetch photos") }

       //save `localIdentifier` for later use (app relaunch or whatever)
       let assetIdentifier = asset.localIdentifier

       print(assetIdentifier)

       //Just a demo that you can get the same asset based on a local identifier
       loadAsset(identifier: assetIdentifier)
   }
   ```
2. Function to load an Asset based on a `localIdentifier`

   ```
   func loadAsset(identifier: String) {
       guard let asset = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withLocalIdentifiers: [identifier],
                                             options: nil).firstObject
           else {
               fatalError("No Asset found with identifier: \(identifier)")
       }

       print(asset.localIdentifier)

       //Do something with the asset now
       if asset.mediaType == .image {
           loadImage(asset: asset)
       }
       else if asset.mediaType == .video {
           loadVideo(asset: asset)
       }
   }
   ```
3. Load an image from a `PHAsset`

   ```
   func loadImage(asset: PHAsset) {
       PHImageManager().requestImageData(for: asset, options: nil) { (data, string, orientation, userInfo) in
           guard let data = data else { fatalError("Image Data is nil") }

           DispatchQueue.main.async {
               self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. Load a video from a `PHAsset`

   ```
   func loadVideo(asset: PHAsset) {
       PHImageManager().requestAVAsset(forVideo: asset, options: nil) { (avAsset, audioMix, userInfo) in
           guard let avAsset = avAsset else { fatalError("AVAsset is nil") }

           let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: avAsset)
           let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
           let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
           playerLayer.frame = self.view.frame
           playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill

           DispatchQueue.main.async {
               self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
               player.play()
           }
       }
   }
   ```

---

PS: You would no longer require `getURL(completionHandler:)` because your entire logic will be based on `localIdentifier`s instead of `url`s and I'll say that's much better.
`Url`s are just, kinda, fickle so lets just avoid them here atleast.

Comment: You’re a great person and this is a great answer! Thank you!

Comment: @K.Wu Thanks,it was but my pleasure :)